# Ubuntu 14.04 & Macbook Pro - Reset Touchpad Settings

Tags: touchpad, macbook-pro, synaptics

How do i reset my touchpad settings to complete defaults?
I've made a bit of a mess of things and installed and uninstalled gpointing-device-settings and mtrack but now all of my settings are messed up.
How would i find and remove the lingering files and restore the touchpad to factory defaults?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by doing the following:

1. Deleted .gconf and all folders relating to gpointing-device-settings from the hidden directories under my home folder
2. Creating a "xorg.conf" in "/etc/X11" with the following:

   Section "InputClass" 
   Identifier         "Touchpad" 
   Driver             "synaptics"
   MatchIsTouchpad    "on"
   Option         "ClickFinger3" "2"
   Option         "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "1"
   Option         "VertScrollDelta" "85"
   Option         "HorizScrollDelta" "85"
   Option         "TapButton1" "0"
   Option         "TapButton2" "0"
   Option         "TapButton3" "0"
   Option         "FingerHigh" "8"
   Option         "FingerLow" "8"
   EndSection