# MacBook Pro touch pad disabled

Tags: touchpad, macbook-pro

Hello I tried to use someone's code to tweak my MacBook pros touchpad. After I executed the commands and rebooted my touchpad does not respond to touch and the cursor is invisible. I have tried updating the kernel, checking if there was an unknown display. Not sure what to do. Here's the code:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse active false
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack
sudo apt-get autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
  Pasted this inside the nano above: 
       Section "InputClass"
 MatchIsTouchpad "on"
 Identifier "Touchpads"
 Driver "mtrack"
 Option "IgnoreThumb" "true"
 Option "IgnorePalm" "true"
 Option "DisableOnPalm" "true"
 Option "BottomEdge" "30"
 Option "TapDragEnable" "false"
 Option "Sensitivity" "1.2"
 Option "ButtonEnable" "true"
 Option "ButtonIntegrated" "true"
 Option "ClickFinger1" "1"
 Option "ClickFinger2" "3"
 Option "TapButton1" "0"
 Option "TapButton2" "0"
 Option "TapButton3" "0"
 Option "TapButton4" "0"
EndSection
```

Also this `echo "pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12" > ~/.Xmodmap`
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... Looks like you were partly lied to. That code disables the touchpad. Luckily, simply reverse it! First, when Ubuntu boots press `Alt+F1` to enter the terminal. Type in your username & password to log in. Once in, run the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse active false
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo apt-get autoremove xserver-xorg-input-mtrack
```

Next, run this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and replace the following:

Driver "mtrack" with Driver "synaptics"

"IgnoreThumb" "true" to "IgnoreThumb" "false"

Hope this helps!

Edit:
If you need more help, here is another answer that may help:
[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579974/ubuntu-14-04-macbook-pro-reset-touchpad-settings?rq=1)

Comment: Wow thanks so much. You really got me out of s jam.

Comment: So I can learn why do the changes you suggested work?

Comment: I reversed the changes that he made. (Well most of them.) Also what wasit supposed to do?